# Работа с cmd Windows

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Надо сделать интерфейс для батника, но не знаю с чего начать, так что сейчас пробую просто выполнить хотябы cmd.exe `ping goo.gl -t` по нажатию кнопки, но дело в том, что в текстовом поле появляется вывод из консоли только после нажатия в ней `ctrl+c`...
может есть у кого какой пример простейший работы с консолью винды?
надо асинхронно выводить что в консоли в richTextBox1 и принимать команды по нажатию кнопки

Comment: Запускай в отдельном процессе, хватай его потоки и читай асинхронно, когда есть данные. По-моему так.

Comment: I think this is what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands
To do it asynchronous you may use async and await keywords.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C ping goo.gl -t");
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    };

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    Console.ReadKey();
    process.Close();
}
```

Более полный ответ на ваш вопрос дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492145/c-sharp-redirecting-cmd-output-to-textbox).